# How to resize image without losing the quality of that image?

Tags: laravel, intervention

I have implemented image intervention in my laravel project. The actual size i need for my image is 370 * 315. When i upload image with aspect ration on it perfectly fits but the quality of image is very very poor even though i have given 100.

***I have tried***

```
$originalImage=Intervention::make(public_path('uploads/360/original').'/'. $filenameImage);

    $thumbHeight=315;
    $thumbWidth=370;

     //for thumbnail images
        $thumbImg = $originalImage;
        $thumbImg->resize( $thumbHeight, $thumbWidth, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save(public_path('uploads/360/thumbnail').'/'. $filenameImage,100);
```

But the image quality is always very very low

Comment: Judged by the indentation it seems like you're performing multiple resizes. Could you show us the whole code?

Comment: @Dan no that's the only resize

Comment: try to add `$constraint->upsize();`

Comment: @AlzafanChristian i saw this as well but couldn't understand

Comment: @AlzafanChristian can you please explain

Comment: @TesushInternational as far as i know, upsizing prevent your original image upsizing too much(bad pixelated pics). except if your original size are lower than the size you want to resize e.g: 200x200px resized to 400x400px.